# object "Entrez" not found Bioconductor R

Tags: r, bioconductor

I have to rank the genes of my dataframe, I found this code from a bioinformatic training course. But if I try to run this, I keep getting the error:  `Error in filter(df, !is.na(Entrez)) : object 'Entrez' not found`

```
library(fgsea)
load("Robjects/Annotated_Results_LvV.RData")

gseaDat <- filter(shrinkLvV, !is.na(Entrez))
ranks <- gseaDat$logFC
names(ranks) <- gseaDat$Entrez
head(ranks)
```

I have no clue how to fix this, am I just missing a package that I have to install?

source: https://bioinformatics-core-shared-training.github.io/cruk-summer-school-2018/RNASeq2018/html/06_Gene_set_testing.nb.html

Comment: Where does `shrinkLvV` come from? What does `names(shrinkLvV)` return?

Comment: I found the shrinkLvV dataframe on a github somewhere, it returns 
```[1] "GeneID"         "baseMean"       "logFC"          "lfcSE"          "stat"          
 [6] "pvalue"         "FDR"            "Entrez"         "Symbol"         "Description"   
[11] "Biotype"        "Chr"            "Start"          "End"            "Strand"        
[16] "medianTxLength" "TopGeneLabel"  ```

Comment: It seems like you are trying to use `dplyr::filter` but maybe have not loaded that package yet. Try adding `library(dplyr)` to the top of the script as well.

Comment: Sadly that didn't change anything, thanks tho

Comment: Try being explicit: `gseaDat <- dplyr::filter()` rather than just `filter()`

Comment: Still the same, I feel like there is a problem specific with the Entrez keyword, but I can't find out what it is

Comment: Well that seems to match one of the values returned by `names(shrinkLvV)`. I notice in the error you posted it uses the variable `df` which does not match the code you posted. Are you sure everything is correct?